# Pasting a raster image into Illustrator, control default PPI

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm using Illustrator to create a presentation and I use images of part of my screen. I basically take a screenshot (actually I use Snagit to only copy a part of my screen, but I don't think that is relevant) and paste it into illustrator. I was expecting the raster image to be paste at the native resolution of the picture, but for some reason, illustrator always scale it to make it 96 PPI. I could just redial the correct numbers in and it would be fine, but I have a large amount of pictures to paste and this is inefficient. Is there a way to change the default pasted image PPI to 72, which is no scaling?

Answer (score 1):

You're on a Windows system right? Windows uses a default pixel density of 96ppi. 72ppi is for Macs.. and neither 72ppi nor 96ppi have been true for over 30 years. Images for the web are displayed at their pixel width and pixel height, not using any ppi setting.

Illustrator offers **no control** over the ppi of placed or pasted raster images.

If you want to alter the ppi of a raster image you need to do it outside of Illustrator then place or paste the raster image at the ppi you want.